# How to check only for few properties Arraylsit.Contains(Object) method should return true?

Tags: java, android, object, arraylist, contains

In my code when i use myarraylist.contains(myobject) it should check only for few proporties of myobject 
how to do it?

one of my object properties changes time to time i dont want to consider that property
but it should be that object

Comment: What have you done so far? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: You should only be using `ArrayList.contains` for equality on all properties.  For anything else, you should be iterating over it and doing the check yourself..

Comment: see [Java List ArrayList override equals method](http://javacodeimpl.blogspot.in/2014/01/java-listarraylist-override-contains.html#.VBpjsZazCKM) example

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to override `equals()` method of your `MyObject` class the way you want to check the contains.

Comment: @SHASHIDHARMANCHUKONDA yes.

Answer (score 0):

Overriding methods is what you need:

```
ArrayList<AnyObject> list = new ArrayList<AnyObject>(){
  @Override
  public boolean contains(AnyObject object){
   //iterate over items and check for properties equality.
 }
}
```

Comment: This is a valid approach, however overriding the `equals()` method as proposed in another answer is the more scalable solution.